# Noneuclidean Geometry - how do I find $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathcal{S}$?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, stereographic-projections, noneuclidean-geometry

[image]

I've been asked to find $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathcal{S}$. I'm stuck on the question attached because although it gives the formula of how to find $\pi_\mathcal{s}$ (stereographic projection), I'm not sure it can be used to find the reverse i.e. $(x,y,z)$. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $\pi_s^{-1}(u, v) = \left(\frac{2u}{1 + u^2 + v^2}, \frac{2 v}{1 + u^2 + v^2}, \frac{-1 + u^2 + v^2}{1 + u^2 + v^2}\right)$

$$\pi_s^{-1}(1, 4) = \left(\frac{2}{18}, \frac{8}{18}, \frac{16}{18}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{9}, \frac{4}{9}, \frac{8}{9}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you. Do you have the name of this formula?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection